# Dividing screen in android like frames in html

Tags: android-layout, html-frames

I am making an android application.
There i want a common navigation menu on every activity like frames in html.
I want the menu at the left (say 20%) area and other navigation screens on the right (say 80% area)

please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use two fragments, that way you keep the menu in one fragment and only change the activity in the other, I should not be difficult to find an example on internet since it is very common in tablets.
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

Comment: Ohhh okay.
Isn't this possible using the layouts?
I mean, why not use a linear layout with two children(linear layouts) with different weights?

Comment: Well...maybe after a huge workaround you will be able to do something similar, but probably using threads, dealing with memory and synchronization...I am not completely sure since I have never done before and I don't think it necessary since fragments are very easy to use and there are a lot of examples.

Remember, don't reinvent the wheel :).

Comment: thanx for the support!
God Bless Computer society! :-)